# why am i getting this error ?"HookWebpackError: File E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\.next\static\media\eho.3e680d06.JPG does not exist."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: File E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio.next\static\media\eho.3e680d06.JPG does not exist.
at makeWebpackError (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:308185)
at E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:105236
at eval (eval at create (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:28771), :27:1)
at E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:68649
at E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:414:143
-- inner error --
Error: File E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio.next\static\media\eho.3e680d06.JPG does not exist.
at Job.emitDependency (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled@vercel\nft\index.js:1:39473)
at async Promise.all (index 19)
at async Object.nodeFileTrace (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled@vercel\nft\index.js:1:35430)
at async E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:135:28
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
at async TraceEntryPointsPlugin.createTraceAssets (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:89:9)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: File E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio.next\static\media\eho.3e680d06.JPG does not exist.
at Job.emitDependency (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled@vercel\nft\index.js:1:39473)
at async Promise.all (index 19)
at async Object.nodeFileTrace (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled@vercel\nft\index.js:1:35430)
at async E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:135:28
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
at async TraceEntryPointsPlugin.createTraceAssets (E:\Project Romulus\3D_portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:89:9)

> Build failed because of webpack errors
> info  - Creating an optimized production build .

i tried to build my nextjs web app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is the link for the repo https://github.com/oli-mac/3D_portfolio.git